# How to fill libgdx body with texture repeatedly?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I know that I can do this throgh using `PolygonRegion` but problem is that I use `scene2d.Stage` and few actors. As you maybe know stages uses `SpriteBatch` and I can't render PolygonRegion (method batch.draw(polygonRegion) is not exist).

Result which I want :

[image]

When I put in my Actor's draw method this code:

```
polygonSpriteBatch.begin();
polygonSpriteBatch.draw(polygonRegion, getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
polygonSpriteBatch.end();
```

I get something like this :

[image]

Comment: Scene2D doesn't have to use SpriteBatch. Pass your PolygonSpriteBatch into the Stage constructor and it will use that. The Stage will be slightly less efficient at drawing rectangular sprites, but in most cases it probably won't matter. You can cast the Batch to PolygonSpriteBatch in your actor's draw method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to me you should use `Stage` at the top of `PolygonSpriteBatch` `draw(..)` call that I mean use `PolygonSpriteBatch` for 2D terrain.

If your required `Actor/Image` is in rectangular size then you can wrap your texture :

```
Texture texture=new Texture("tex1.png");
texture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat, Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat);
textureRegion=new TextureRegion(texture,300,300);
```

---

Create `PolygonSpriteBatch` object and pass in Stage's constructor.

```
stage=new Stage(new ScalingViewport(Scaling.stretch, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), new OrthographicCamera()),new PolygonSpriteBatch());
```

For more cohesiveness, you can create own Stage by inheritance.

Then create `Actor` class that handle/draw your `PolygonRegion` of particular texture image.

```
public class PolyActor extends Actor {

  PolygonRegion polygonRegion;

  public PolyActor(PolygonRegion region){
      this.polygonRegion=region;
  }

  @Override
  public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {

    Color color = getColor();
    batch.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a * parentAlpha);
    ((PolygonSpriteBatch)batch).draw(polygonRegion,getX(),getY());
  }
}
```

Create `PolyActor` and add to Stage, Below are my test code and output :

```
float a = 100;
float b = 100;

PolygonRegion polygonRegion=new PolygonRegion(textureRegion,new float[] {
            a*0, b*0,
            a*0, b*2,
            a*1, b*2,
            a*1.5f, b*1.5f,
            a*3, b*1.5f,
            a*3.5f, b*1,
            a*4, b*1,
            a*4.5f, b*1.5f,
            a*5f, b*1.5f,
            a*5f, b*0f},new short[] {
            0, 1, 2,1,2,3,0,2,3,0,3,4,0,4,5,0,5,6,0,6,9,6,7,9,7,8,9
 });

 PolyActor polyActor =new PolyActor(polygonRegion);
 polyActor.setPosition(75,0);
 stage.addActor(polyActor);
```

Texture that I used :

[image]

And my expected output :

[image]

**EDIT**

`Texture` is nothing more than 2D array of bytes at GPU memory. This 2D array have size and those bytes are interpreted as colors usually. Scaling of byte data don't make scene but you can pretty much use this data how you want.

Either you can create own scaled Texture by `Pixmap` :

```
Pixmap originalPix = new Pixmap(Gdx.files.internal("badlogic.jpg"));  // 256 * 256
Pixmap scaledPix = new Pixmap(700, 700, originalPix.getFormat());
scaledPix.drawPixmap(originalPix, 0, 0, originalPix.getWidth(), originalPix.getHeight(), 0, 0, scaledPix.getWidth(), scaledPix.getHeight());
Texture texture = new Texture(scaledPix);  // 400 * 400
originalPix.dispose();
scaledPix.dispose();
```

Comment: Can you also tell me how to scale texture which is in PolygonRegion?

Comment: `draw` method of `PolygonSpriteBatch` is overloaded, use method that having scaling factor.

Comment: But I don&#39;t want to scale the entire PolygonRegion. I want to scale source texture which we use to create PolygonRegion

Comment: @RedLipsAlwaysLie I've edited my answer, please check